# Adding new hard disk to a RHEL9 virtual machine

Tags: linux, rhel, hard-disk, vmware

It's my first post here, so forgive me if I don't provide enough info. I'm also a beginner Linux user as well.

At the moment I'm going through Sander Van Vugt's RHCSA RHEL 9 course and I'm fairly satisfied, besides some small grievances. I'm going through creating new partitions, formatting file systems etc. and it's all clear, but I have a problem:

For my lab assignment, he simply requests "add a new 10GB hard disk and then add partition...", and I don't know how to do this. I know how to extend the current hard disk, partition it, mount it permanently and all that, but that's not what is asked.

He never shows how to do it and he already had two NVMe disks added since the beginning of the course. When I add a new disk through VMware, I can't select it to be a NVMe type (my main disk is NVMe) so I made a SCSI, but when I try to boot up, it tries to boot from that disk and it ignores the main one where I already have a system.

So, my question is: how can I add a hard disk to an existing VM, most efficiently? I've found some solutions already, but the situation is not the same as I have, so I don't want to do things without understanding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't a Linux question but a VMware question whether you are using VMware Workstation Player, VMware Workstation, or your own,ESXI host. TWhile there is a way in Vsphere to add an NVME controller, that's not important and nowhere does it say in your question that this is needed. There are plenty of guides on Google and Youtube that cover adding a hard disk to an existing virtual machine in VMware. It's not difficult and as long as you don't mess with anything else, you can delete the disk that you add and start again if you make a mistake.